# hooking javascript file in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

my problem is I am trying to call up some javascript code and create a plugin with it.

I added both files into the plugin directory in a folder and wordpress recognizes the plugin. But I must have done something wrong because the .js file is said to be inactive and does not work.

I'm inexperienced with this, can anyone point out my error? Or point me in the right direction?

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('downloadimagescript', plugins_url() . '/js/downloadimagescript.js', array('jquery'));

    admin_enqueue_scripts('downloadimagescript');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

Comment: You've got a `.` instead of a `+` in your register script text

Comment: concatenation in php is with a `.`

Comment: Are you trying to enqueue scripts for just the admin area? If not, might want to try the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action

Answer (score 0):

The path to your js is probably wrong, as `plugins_url()` [returns the plugins directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) e.g. "http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins". Add your plugin's directory name before `/js/...`